# Go playground url validate

Tags: go, go-playground

I am sending a request which has a `URL and Content` in the body. The validations are such that either URL or epicentre is mandatory. The program is erroring when the URL is empty as `url validate` on an empty string is failing.

Is there a way to run url validate on URL only if its non empty?

Heres my code snippet.

```
func (d *Doc) UnmarshalJSON(bytearray []byte) error {
    type doc struct {
        ID           ID      `json:"id" validate:"omitempty,numeric"`
        URL          string  `json:"url" validate:"required_without=Content,url"`
        Content      string  `json:"content" validate:"required_without=Url"`
    
    }
    var d doc
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytearray, &d); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try omitempty?

Answer (score -1):

There was a similar question raised as an [issue within the repo](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/issues/308) and the suggestion was to use struct level validation.

Example usage within validator examples: https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/v9/_examples/struct-level/main.go#L48

The following is untested but should be a good starting point:

```
import (
    "json"
    "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"
)

func init() {
    validate.RegisterStructValidation(DocStructLevelValidation, doc{})
}

type doc struct {
    ID           ID      `json:"id" validate:"omitempty,numeric"`
    URL          string  `json:"url"`
    Content      string  `json:"content"`
}

func DocStructLevelValidation(sl validator.StructLevel) {
    d := sl.Current().Interface().(doc)

    if d.URL == "" && d.Content == "" {
        sl.ReportError(d.URL, "url", "URL", "urlcontentrequired", "")
        sl.ReportError(d.Content, "content", "Content", "urlcontentrequired", "")
    }
}

func (d *Doc) UnmarshalJSON(bytearray []byte) error {
    var d doc
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytearray, &d); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```